# How to use/link meson build Gstreamer in ROS Package?

Tags: ros, package.xml, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

E.g
To use Gstreamer, I meson built new version with following commands.

```
meson --prefix=/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed --reconfigure build/  
ninja -C build/  
meson install -C build/
```

Now I have this directory
[image: image description]

And it has pkg-configs also
[image: image description]

**What changes I have to make in Cmakelist.txt & package.xml** to link this Gstreamer?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339225/how-to-use/link-meson-build-gstreamer-in-ros-package?/) by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-12-05**:
You can take a look [here](https://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_libraries.html).

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2019-12-26**:
@Choco93, Thanks

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2019-12-30**:
**I have tried below changes. But no luck till now.**

Cmakelist.txt

```
SET(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "/media/jai/Entertainment/Software/gstreamer/gst-build-installed/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig" $ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GST1.0 REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0)
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
    DEPENDS Boost GST1.0
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES mypkg)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GST1.0_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(mypkg ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GST1.0_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

package.xml

```
<build_depend>pkg-config</build_depend>
```

**After all above modification, package is still using stock gstreamer instead of new one.**
I doubt it might be able to access include files but not LIBS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered at
[How to use/link meson build Gstreamer in ROS Package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534823/how-to-use-link-meson-build-gstreamer-in-ros-package)

---

Originally posted by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) with karma: 62 on 2020-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0